# glm binomial regression. How can I check what output is predicting

Tags: r, statistics, regression, logistic-regression, glm

Stupid question, but I want to be sure.
`glm(outcome ~ cva, family = "binomial", data=df, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)`

```
Predictors  Odds    p
(Intercept) 0.16    <0.001
cvaTRUE     1.95    0.029
```

My 'outcome' variable is YES or NO as.factor

How can I be sure this glm is giving the Odds of YES and not NO?
ie I want to be confident that this is saying "if cva TRUE then Odds 1.95 for outcome YES.

Answer (score 1):

With a binary response taking the value of either 0 or 1, the model estimates the odds that `outcome` is equal to 1. So, if YES is coded as 1 then you can be sure that the odds of 1.95 are for outcome YES.

Answer (score 0):

If `outcome` is a factor with levels `"NO"` and `"YES"` and `cva` is a logical vector, then

```r
coef(glm(outcome ~ cva, family = binomial, data = df))
```

shows you (per unit changes in) log odds of `"YES"` rather than `"NO"` *if and only if* `"NO"` is the first element of `levels(outcome)`. This requirement is documented in `?family`:

> For the binomial and quasibinomial families the response can be specified in one of three ways:
>
> 1. As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not having the first level (and hence usually of having the second level).

If you find that `outcome` is not coded this way, then do

```r
df$outcome <- relevel(df$outcome, "NO")
```

to replace `outcome` in `df` with a semantically equivalent factor whose first level is `"NO"`.

FWIW, here is one way to check that `glm` behaves as documented in your use case:

```r
## Simulated data set
set.seed(1L)
n <- 100L
df <- data.frame(
  outcome = factor(sample(0:1, size = n, replace = TRUE), levels = 0:1, labels = c("NO", "YES")),
  cva = sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), size = n, replace = TRUE)
)

## Contingency table
tt <- table(df$outcome, df$cva)

## Sample odds ratio
r <- (tt["YES", "TRUE"] / tt["NO", "TRUE"]) / (tt["YES", "FALSE"] / tt["NO", "FALSE"])
## Estimated odds ratio when first level is "NO"
m0 <- glm(outcome ~ cva, family = binomial, data = df)
r0 <- exp(coef(m0))[[2L]]
## Reciprocal estimated odds ratio when first level is "YES"
m1 <- glm(relevel(outcome, "YES") ~ cva, family = binomial, data = df)
r1 <- exp(-coef(m1))[[2L]]

print(c(r, r0, r1), digits = 20, width = 30)
```

```
[1] 0.85565476190476186247
[2] 0.85565476230266901414
[3] 0.85565476230266912516
```