# glm binomial regression. How can I check what output is predicting, level function not working

Tags: r, glm

I have the same question as posted here ([glm binomial regression. How can I check what output is predicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656322/glm-binomial-regression-how-can-i-check-what-output-is-predicting/75483367?noredirect=1#comment133180704_75483367)) and tried to check it with levels(outcome) as it was suggested in the answer. However, it is not working for me for some reason:

```
glm( factor(mgroup) ~ factor(sex) + age  +  factor(Site_Category)  + expr, 
              data = pheno, family = binomial)
```

I tried:

```
> levels(mgroup)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'levels': object 'mgroup' not found
> levels(outcome)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'levels': object 'outcome' not found
> levels(factor(mgroup))
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'levels': object 'mgroup' not found
```

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,
Bine

Tried to run the command as suggested in the solution but it is not working.

Comment: As the error message says Sally, `mgroup` does not exist. It is a column within `pheno`, so you need `levels(pheno$mgroup)`. However, I would tend to change a character column to 1s and 0s if doing a glm just so that I can be certain what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you Allan, I have tried this and it only says the following: > levels(pheno$mgroup)
NULL

Comment: pheno$mgroup
   [1] "no mets [2] "mets" are the two options for .So when you say changing character column to 1 and 0, how would you do that?

Comment: I think I solved it myself. Command levels(pheno$mgroup) works when I load the csv file with stringsAsFactors=TRUE. So the first one is the one I am predicting the output for, or? So in my case mets: > levels(pheno$mgroup)
[1] "mets"    "no mets"